# How can I know who's not following me back on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I want to know if there's an application or website that can help me know who are the people that are not following me back, I have 3,549 followers but I'm following 3,612. So I'll like to know who are those users that don't follow back, because it's not easy to go to every URL of every username and know if they are following me or not. I've googled it and the things I found are not available for download anymore.

Comment: [Missing E](http://missing-e.com) used to do this but they had to shut the functionality down at Tumblr's request. No idea who else has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the XKit extension pack. I don't think it automatically includes the follower checker when you install it, but you can add it with ease. It tells you both whom you follow that doesn't follow you back and anyone who unfollows you after you install it.

EDIT: here's the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dbnboehlfeemlfpefilcplpcjofkegnn?hl=en&gl=TR).

Answer (score 1):

We just extended our Twitter app (Friend or Follow) to allow people to see who's not following them back on Tumblr, and vice versa. You might be interested in it. http://tumblr.friendorfollow.com/

Comment: If you could update your info section http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/19207/dusty-reagan with your affiliation that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt it is possible without using [Tumblr's API](http://missing-e.com/faq#apiissues). Seeing that Tumblr pages this data, it would just not be feasible to create a bot that monitors this list constantly without the API.

Of course you can also just use your own application *locally* utilizing the following calls

- `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/following`
- `http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/{base-hostname}/followers`

As long as you ensure [respect for API Limitations](http://www.tumblr.com/policy/en/api)